# Examples showing the usefulness of derived categories

Tags: homology-cohomology

What are examples that show that derived categories *really* makes things easier/more transparent/have a real use?

Comment: You may want to [read some of the pointers given 
here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39398/derived-category-and-so-on).

Comment: Do you like Morita equivalence? :-) It can be generalized in presence of differential structures, and even A-infty structures using derived categories. In general, derived categories are quite natural if you want to study structures with differentials (like complexes of modules over a given ring) identifying those structures which give the same information, i.e. cohomology. Localization w.r.t. quasi-isomorphisms is the method behind this idea.